# is AWS EC2 `Import key pairs` the same as adding public keys to `authorized_keys`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm trying to familiarized myself with AWS key pairs feature.

I have manually added a public key generated by my Cloud9 into `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on my EC2 server. I can view it and successfully log into my instance using Cloud9 IDE.
However, this key doesn't show up when I view my instance's key pairs.

In the mean time, I created a test key pair, imported the public key onto my instance through `Import key pair` feature from the console, and gave it a name. It went through successfully.
However, when I view my `authorized_keys` file, this newly imported key is not there!

I suspect that manually adding public keys into the `authorized_keys` file is not the same as the console `Import key pair` feature at all.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, they're not the same thing.

When you import a keypair using the AWS console, that activity is not associated with an EC2 instance. What you're doing is importing public key material, giving it a name, and asking AWS to store it in a database for your use in the future. It changes nothing in terms of running EC2 instances.

The next time you launch an EC2 instance, you can choose this new keypair, and it will be injected by EC2 into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the running EC2 instance. In this way, you can SSH into the instance because you have the matching private key (*you* have it, AWS does not have it).

At this point you could delete the keypair from AWS and it would make no difference to the running EC2 instance, or to your ability to SSH into it. It *would*, of course, prevent you launching a second EC2 instance with that same keypair.

If you SSH to an EC2 instance and manually inject a new public key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` then you can immediately SSH to that instance using the corresponding private key. You are on your own at this point, manually managing SSH keys.

Comment: Are all public keys residing in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` equal? There is no order of priority or `key that rules all`?

Comment: I'm not sure how any priority, if there were such a thing, would matter. The decision is ultimately go or no-go if any one of the public keys is a pair to the private key. I don't know for certain that there isn't a priority, but I strongly doubt it.